# Websphere works when run but fails when debug

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere

I'm using Intellij with WebSphere 8. When I run from within IDE the server works normally. When I try to run it in debug mode however, it fails with the following error:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin\generated_websphere_server_start_script.cmd
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin\java -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\runtimes\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\plugins\webSphereIntegration\lib\webSphereIntegration.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-impl.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\lib\openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\plugins\webSphereIntegration\lib\specifics\webSphereClientImpl.jar" com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 62847 com.intellij.j2ee.webSphere.agent.WebSphereAgent
Error: JDWP agent already loaded - please check java command line options
[2014-08-11 01:58:59,248] Artifact x.ear: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
JVMJ9TI064E Agent initialization function Agent_OnLoad failed for library jdwp, return code -1
Detected server admin port: 8880
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti26(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
Detected server http port: 9080
Disconnected from server
```

I tried almost everything I have no idea what the problem is. I did google it for several hours with no luck.

Do anyone know what this all is about and how can it be fixed?

Here is my server configuration:
[image: first]
[image: second]

Comment: Can you please post your server configuration on InteliJ. Somehow it looks like the debugger command or client is being double launched as by this message: 
Error: JDWP agent already loaded - please check java command line options

Comment: Check the server debug settings [in the admin console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html?locale=en#JavaVirtualMachine_debugMode_description).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution 1
unchecked the Pass environment variables check box and restart the server in debug mode. it should work properly.

Run --> Edit Configuration --> websphere server --> Startup/Conections tab
select debug, you will see the Pass environment variables check box. it need to be unchecked for debug to work.

Solution 2
if debug mode of websphere is working in eclipse and not working in intellij that reason i found out is debugging serverice on the websphere is already started and intellij is again trying to start the debggin service. so stop the service from websphere console (Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > [serverName] > Debugging Service) and all the default configurations in intellij should work.

Comment: Solution #1 worked for me. Do you know why we have to uncheck this environment variable setting in IDEA?

Comment: One can start WebSphere by default in a debug mode (configured through the WebSphere (web) Console. But also by adding JVM options on the command line (InetlliJ uses this). But enabling both ways, causes issues, as WebSphere will not know which options have the highest priority or some might even conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Finally I figure it out. I hope this solution helps.  I'm using Intellij idea 2019.1.3.. and  WebSphere 8.5.5.13

- check WebSphere start server script find debug env variable name (in my script  (WebSphere\AppServer\bin\startServer.bat)
  **WAS_DEBUG**)
- add same debug option name to intelliJ IDEA
- run- debug configuration environment tab.

[image: default debug env name]
[image: env passed args]

**Since default env variable is debug and cannot be overridden**

- check pass env variables
- add WAS_DEBUG option as I did
- or you can update WAS_DEBUG  as DEBUG (same as default in IntelliJ) in server startup.bat script.

  Both  should work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old, but i was able to experience too!

They will try to fix this now in: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193580

Answer (score 0):

firstly, sorry if the translation is not good, I am Brazilian and I would like to share the solution I made.

First: Locate the file "startServer.bat in "WebSphere\AppServer\bin" and open it with any text editor.

Second: Search for the second incidence of the word "WAS_DEBUG" and replace it with "DEBUG", as shown in the image...

Third: In Intellij, go to the server settings and in the "Startup/Connection" tab, select debug.

Fourth: Now uncheck the "use default" checkbox in "Startup script" and point to the location of the "startServer.bat" file in the webSphere directory.

Fifth: Right on the left side of the checkbox, there is an option to enter a parameter. Click and a "Program Arguments" field will appear. Enter the server name, in my case it was "server1".

Okay, now just test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCDIm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMgdw.png)